# Suffix Array Implementation Bugs

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, suffix-array

I've coded a Suffix Array implementation and discovered an issue in my implementation. Concretely I've outputted the first few suffix array ranks `RA[0..7]` of this [string](http://pastebin.com/5VsTzcFX)(length = 10^5) and had the following output:

```
80994
84360
87854
91517
95320
99277
83068
```

But the correct one had to be (everything shifted by 23):

```
81017
84383
87877
91540
95343
99300
83091
```

I know two ways how to fix it, but I don't know why it worked.

The first way was adding `S[N++] = '$';` to the top of the `buildSA()` function (then the output was 1 less than the correct one, but it doesn't matter)

I also found another solution by decreasing the MAX_N constant to 1e5 + 10!

This is so much magic for me and I really need to know why this bug happened because I don't want to have this bug again.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
using std::max;
const int MAX_N = 2e5 + 10;
int SA[MAX_N];   // The ith element is the index of the suffix
int RA[MAX_N];   // The rank of the suffix at i
int tmp[MAX_N];  // A temporary array
int B[MAX_N];    // An array for the buckets
int N;
char S[MAX_N];

void bucketSort(int k){
  int i, m = max(256, N);
  for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
    B[i] = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    B[i + k < N ? RA[i + k] : 0] ++;
  for(i = 1; i < m; i++)
    B[i] += B[i - 1];
  for(i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    tmp[--B[SA[i] + k < N ? RA[SA[i] + k] : 0]] = SA[i];
  for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    SA[i] = tmp[i];
}

void buildSA(){
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    SA[i] = i;
    RA[i] = S[i];
  }
  for(int k = 1; k < N; k <<= 1){
    bucketSort(k);
    bucketSort(0);
    int norder = 0;
    tmp[SA[0]] = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < N; i++){
      if(RA[SA[i]] == RA[SA[i - 1]] && RA[SA[i] + k] == RA[SA[i - 1] + k])
      {} else norder++;
      tmp[SA[i]] = norder;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      RA[i] = tmp[i];
    if(norder == N)
      break;
  }
}

void printSA(){
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    printf("%d: %s\n", SA[i], S + SA[i]);
  }
}

int main(){
  scanf("%s", S);
  N = strlen(S);
  buildSA();
  for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    printf("%d\n",RA[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't have a problem with being asked to fing bugs (some SOers do), but you have to make an effort by finding a *smallest possible* input that triggers it.

Comment: (Looking for a small input that triggers the bug is one of the first things you should do in the process of *trying to fix it yourself*.)

Comment: random testing helps find a small problematic input.

Comment: I've done it already and ran the test generator for like two hours...

Comment: The key to understanding why a bug happens is to understand the algorithm you are writing (i.e. you're not just copying someone elses code). If you don't understand your algorithm, and it appears to you to be "magic", then understanding how to fix it is going to be extremely difficult, and is going to typically involve making semi-random changes until you hit on something that seems to "work", at least until it doesn't, and just perpetuates the perspective of it being "magic"...

Comment: If it helps, the used test data was actually the string used in COCI 2013/14 Contest #1 Task SLASTIČAR filename is slasticar.in.10a

Comment: I've got the bug! :) But I can't answer my own question now because I'm a newbie :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following line:
`if(RA[SA[i]] == RA[SA[i - 1]] && RA[SA[i] + k] == RA[SA[i - 1] + k])`
`SA[i] + k` can be >=`N`(the same is for `SA[i - 1] + k`).
It should be `(SA[i] + k) % N`instead.

Comment: That's true. I verified this by using a very simple testcase (I couldn't generate randomly...) like:

    abab

The resulting suffix array was

    0: abab
    2: ab
    3: b
    1: bab

which is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it after many wasted hours. Sometimes the littlest mistakes can literally result to wrong answers.

The "bad" code line is:

```
if(RA[SA[i]] == RA[SA[i - 1]] && RA[SA[i] + k] == RA[SA[i - 1] + k])
      {} else norder++;
```

I verified this by using a very simple testcase (I couldn't generate randomly...) like:

```
abab
```

The resulting suffix array was

```
0: abab
2: ab
3: b
1: bab
```

which is clearly wrong.

At step k = 2, if we are comparing two suffixes like `ab` and `abab` then, we realize that they have the same rank, since their first k = 2 characters match. `ab` is suffix #2, by adding k = 2, we are out of range.

I've often coded it like this because I've always appended an auxiliary character (e.g. '$') to the end. If I don't put such a character (like in my case), SA[i] + k could actually be >= N and this code crashes.